# Specifications other than OpenAPI Specification to document a restful API

Tags: rest, openapi, specifications

First to have a clear idea of the OpenAPI Specification itself is, let's see how it is defined on its official website (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification):

> The goal of The OpenAPI Specification is to define a standard,
> language-agnostic interface to REST APIs which allows both humans and
> computers to discover and understand the capabilities of the service
> without access to source code, documentation, or through network
> traffic inspection

**Question:** OpenAPI defines a specification on how an API documentation needs to be written in YAML or JSON. Now the question arises if it is the only specification out there to do this job? Or there are other alternatives for the same?

I had my research online, but came to no conclusion.

---

**Note:** This question might be asked to software recommendation, but as "Specification" cannot be called "Software" I decided to ask it on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got to an online course from Pluralsight, **Five Essential Tools for Building REST APIs**, and could find the following two tools as alternatives of OpenAPI Specifiations:

- RAML (http://raml.org/)
- API blueprint (https://apiblueprint.org/)

These are two alternatives for OpenAPI Specifications, and are to some extent newer and richer in their specifications. However, as they very new, they are not well recognized by organizations, and tooling support is limited. Most of their tools they currently support are cloud based.